# how to stop css hover out with a conditional

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 buttons on a box... the box has a css:hover, I would like to "stop" the unhover if the mouse is on the buttons...
I can use js, but I prefer to do not. It's the last alternative.

My code:

http://jsfiddle.net/SXj2W/3/

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
.annimation{
    webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.annimation:hover{
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px) scale(5, 5);
    transform: translate(100px, 100px) scale(5, 5);
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onMouseOut(self,event) {    
    var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    while(e &amp;&amp; e.parentNode &amp;&amp; e.parentNode != window) {
        if (e.parentNode == self||  e == self) {
            if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    //do some shit
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="z-index:1;width: 10px;position:absolute;" id="buttons"><div style="width:10px;height:10px;position:relative;float:left;background-color: rgb(0,255,0);"></div><div style="width:10px;height:10px;position:relative;float:left;background-color: rgb(0,255,0);"></div></div>
<div onmouseout="onMouseOut(this,event)" style="width:50px; height:50px;overflow:hidden;" class="annimation" id="father">
    <div style="margin-top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;transition: margin 2s;" id="container">
        <div onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.marginTop='-50px'" style="width: 50px;height:50px;background-color:rgb(255,0,0);"></div>
        <div onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.marginTop='0px'" style="width: 50px;height:50px;background-color:rgb(0,0,255);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with the animation set up on the box. There's no relationship between the box and the buttons... because they aren't actually within the context of the box, their events are not going to be able to bubble up to the box, so your only real choice is to use javascript the whole way, and not use the :hover for the mouseover functionality, so you can tie the event triggers together.

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: In order for the buttons to be visible, they have to be "on-top" of the father div. The only way to get the animation to ignore the buttons would be through the use of JS.

I see you already have some script, so might I ask why you are opposed to using JS to solve this?

Comment: @JoshKG the fiddle lik was always there.

Comment: I solved the problem with css, I'm posting the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/SXj2W/5/

```
<html><head>

  <style type="text/css">
    .annimation{
    webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.annimation #buttons{
    width:2px;
    height:2px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.annimation:hover #buttons{
    width:2px;
    height:2px;
    visibility:visible;
}
.annimation:hover{
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px) scale(5, 5);
    transform: translate(100px, 100px) scale(5, 5);
}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//&lt;![CDATA[ 

function onMouseOut(self,event) {    
   var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    while(e &amp;&amp; e.parentNode &amp;&amp; e.parentNode != window) {
        if (e.parentNode == self||  e == self) {
            if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    //do some shit
}
//]]&gt;  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div onmouseout="onMouseOut(this,event)" style="width:50px; height:50px;overflow:hidden;" class="annimation" id="father">
    <div style="z-index:1;width: 2px;position:absolute;" id="buttons"><div style="width:2px;height:2px;position:relative;float:left;background-color: rgb(0,255,0);" onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.marginTop='0px'"></div><div style="width:2px;height:2px;position:relative;float:left;background-color: rgb(0,255,0);" onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.marginTop='-50px'"></div></div>
    <div style="margin-top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;transition: margin 2s;" id="container">
        <div onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.marginTop='-50px'" style="width: 50px;height:50px;background-color:rgb(255,0,0);"></div>
        <div onclick="document.getElementById('container').style.marginTop='0px'" style="width: 50px;height:50px;background-color:rgb(0,0,255);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This is not a CSS solution as much as it is an HTML solution. While it is the way to fix your problem, it follows on the advice of the comments in your question and the answer from @Owen 'Coves' Jones, all of whom were correct to point out that you needed to put the buttons divs inside your animation div to create a parent child relationship able to be targetted by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use JS.

The only way to stop this would be having the buttons as a direct child of the initial hovered element, and you've already said you can't do that, so JS is your only resort really.

Comment: You solved it with an HTML restructuring techinque, not really with CSS.